# PDFBox getText not returning all of the visible text

Tags: pdf, pdfbox, text-extraction

I am using PDFBox to extract text from my PDF document. It retrieves the text, but not all of it (specifically, seems like title/header and footer texts are missing). The parts that are missing are not images and are extracted when using text view in foxit reader.

I am using version 1.8.12 and made a test case with 2.0.2 just to see if it would return more of the content.

This is the code i used for 2.0.2:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    File file = new File("D:\\\\file.pdf");
    try {
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);
        PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        //stripper.setSuppressDuplicateOverlappingText(false);
        stripper.getText(doc);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exc errirs ");
    }
}
```

Now I wonder are there any settings I missed? Is PDFBox failing because text is on top of some decorative elements (rectangle under text)?

Thanks

EDIT: [link to file in question](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14898138/03%20WP%20Enterprise%20BlackBerry%20Compete%20Datasheet_041612%20FINAL%20DRAFT.pdf)

Comment: Please share a PDF with which one can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Added link in the question

Comment: And which text is missing? On page 1 the very first "Windows Phone" line with the leading symbol is not writing but vector graphics. The remaining lines "Windows Phone:" and "Empowering Business" are extracted by PDFBox. They probably don't appear where you expect them but they are there.

Comment: @LovroGregorčič Please try the `setSortByPosition(true)` option. This brings better results in some cases.

Comment: You are indeed both correct. Thank you and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr `SortByPosition` indeed would make the page header line here appear first. Unfortunately, though, the page content is layout'ed in two columns; the extraction of this will suffer in case of `SortByPosition` set to `true`.

Comment: @LovroGregorčič The best would be to delete the question, or to answer it yourself, to avoid having "orphans".

Comment: I agree, please change one of the comments into answer, i want to give credits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the text wasn't missing, but at the "wrong" position. By default, PDFBox text extraction extracts the characters as they come in the content stream, but they don't always come in a "natural" way. PDF files are created by software, not by humans.

An alternative is to use the sort option:

```
stripper.setSortByPosition(true)
```

However, as mkl pointed out, if the text is in two columns, you won't like the result either.